# Calling graphql api on AWS with Cognito user pool id

Tags: c#, .net-core, graphql, amazon-cognito, aws-appsync

I spent two days googling for a solution. But couldn't find a proper solution. 
I am provided with the following information.

```
Cognito Identity pool ids: 
INT: "us-east-1:xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx"
CRT: "us-east-1:xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx"
PSS: "us-east-1:xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx"
PREPROD: "us-east-1:xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx"
PROD: "us-east-1:xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx"

Api url : https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.appsync-api.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/graphql
Api id : 63xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
Appsync name : TheAppSyncName
Authorization mechanism : IAM auth
```

I found there are few different ways to do this in Android, https://github.com/awslabs/aws-mobile-appsync-sdk-android

But no example could be found with .net c# AWS sdk.

Can someone please explain the meaning of the above values and how it can be used to call the graphql API in .net C#?

Update:
After trying multiple times I ended up without any solution. Then I found the appsync can't be used with the given information in c# .net. I was provided with the AWS account number and unauth role ARN in addition to above.

Comment: You mention Cognito User Pools, however, you list your Authorization Method as IAM. Are you using [multiple authorizations](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mobile/using-multiple-authorization-types-with-aws-appsync-graphql-apis/)?

Comment: No I'm not using multiple authorizations. But these are the details i'm provided with with no description at all. I would like to know a way of getting this done, in any of the 4 ways of authentication.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56838587/11376091) will provide you with some context about the AWS SDK.

As that answer mentions, the AWS SDK **does not provide a way invoke your API**. To invoke you API it is as simple as making a post request to your API url.
There are a lot of answers about using postman for AppSync, which will help you understand the topic:

- [how to send graphql query by postman](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42520663/how-to-send-graphql-query-by-postman)
- [how do I integrate amazon cognito login in postman](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52287506/how-do-i-integrate-amazon-cognito-login-in-postman)

Once you understand that you should be able to do the same with any HTTP client of your choosing.

Comment: I ended up using the HTTP client in .net. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/signature-version-4.html gave an overview. But this git repo (https://github.com/FantasticFiasco/aws-signature-version-4) saved a lot of time for me. 

In addition, I had to get the AWS account number in order to use the CognitoAWSCredentials. Will post the complete answer for others reference in a while.